# Database schema for marketplace[posts_attributes]

Tags: mysql, database-design, php

Okay so I am making a marketplace type of website like olx etc.. users can post different types of posts meaning the fields change so I made an extra table called posts_attributes which those changing fields get saved in.

My current problem is when i want to display the posts attributes i want to display a title next to it, for example, lets say the user posted a car for sale now in the brand[input] field he entered volvo and the text volvo will get saved in the posts_attributes table when I want to display it i don't want to display just volvo I want to display Brand: volvo,
but if a user is selling a house he will be asked the amount to bedrooms which he then will enter 2 or 3 etc.. then that will also be saved in posts_attributes. which again should be displayed as Bedrooms: 3.

How would I be able to do this with my current database schema or another type of schema?

**How posts gets saved in db[post_ad.php]**

*please ignore all the variables just assume they are all text except for $ad_body that is an array*

```
                date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Yangon");
                $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
                $stmt = $conn_posts-> prepare("INSERT INTO `posts`(`ad_title`, `ad_sub_cat`, `ad_price`, `used_new`, `for_r_s`,`ad_location`,`ad_poster`, `ad_des`, `ad_date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); //query
                $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $ad_title, $ad_sub_cat,$ad_price,$ad_used_new,$ad_for_r_s,$ad_loc,$_SESSION['user_ID'],$ad_des, $date); // bind_param / insert info
                $stmt->execute(); // execute
                $stmt->store_result(); // store results
                $last_id = $conn_posts->insert_id; //get id of post
                if($stmt->affected_rows == 1){
                    foreach($ad_body as $data){
                        $stmt_atr = $conn_posts-> prepare("INSERT INTO `posts_attributes`(`post_id`,`post_attribute`) VALUES (?,?)"); //query
                        $stmt_atr->bind_param("ss",$last_id,$data); // bind_param / insert info
                        $stmt_atr->execute(); // execute
                        $stmt_atr->store_result(); // store results
                    }
                    if($stmt_atr->affected_rows >= 1){
                        header('location:ad?id='.$last_id.'');
                        exit();
                    }else{
                        $errors[] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your ad. D:/paf102";
                    }
                }else{
                    $errors[] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your ad. D:/paa102";
                }
```

This is my Database Schema built with Lucidchart

[image]

I know there is a lot of PHP but I just recently saw this site and maybe it might work better for my database questions. i am sorry if this question is not in relation to the rules and please ask or tell me anything and i will immediately supply info or fix my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What database system are you using?...please update your question's tags accordingly.

As far as schema design, if your `posts_attributes` table is where you're storing the "Volvo" and "3" values, then you should have a field called `attribute_value` that stores it and the `post_attribute` field goes away. You can then add an `attribute_title` field too, which can store things like "Brand" and "Bedrooms".

Though you should have a normalized table of the unique list of `attribute_titles` and only store the `id` of the title itself in your `posts_attributes` table. In which case, the field in your `posts_attributes` table will actually be called `attribute_title_id`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing and I already started but how would I save the ```attribute_title_id``` with the attribute_value because as you can see from my ad_post.php page it gets added with a for each which is an array of the fields that the users added like Brand and amount of doors and color etc...

Comment: @DB_cont Does your User define the `attribute_title` or are they forced to choose it from an existing place in the application?

Comment: it is a user define input here is the html `<input name="body[]" placeholder="Brand"></input>` and if it is in the house category it will be `<input name="body[]" placeholder="Bedrooms"></input>`

Comment: I made it like this because now i can just check the category id and change the form based on which main category was selected with a simple file include meaning the form will change.

Comment: @DB_cont ok so the only place the `attribute_title` lives currently is in your HTML code?

Comment: oh sorry wait I saw it wrong no `attribute_title` is not a user define it should be based on the category like house or car then if it is volvo that means that it is Brand

Comment: okay, so I did the following @J.D. i said `if($cat == 4){$att_title = array('1', '2','4');}` then on my insert query I changed my forloop Please look at the comment below

Comment: `foreach (array_combine($ad_body, $att_title) as $data => $title){
                        $stmt_atr = $conn_posts-> prepare("INSERT INTO `posts_attributes`(`post_id`,`attribute_title`,`post_attribute`) VALUES (?,?,?)"); //query
                        $stmt_atr->bind_param("sss",$last_id,$title,$data); // bind_param / insert info
                        $stmt_atr->execute(); //execute
                        $stmt_atr->store_result(); // store results
                    }`